# Emergency prompt after Upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade, 16.04

I am sorry I am a wannabe
I just upgraded my E5800 ntel machine based from 14.4 to 16.4 
When it tries to reboot goes in emercy prompt.
I tried to read the journal and i foun some error in mounting the HD.
The system boots regularly in windows XP :(

I Have no Idea of what to do.
Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you Jyves. I Aldo found this errore "unable to remount root and kernel". It seems  my HD deve moved from hda to hdb

Comment: OK The system comes up if  I select the second option of  Ubuntu option at Grub prompt.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to repair your grub with the boot-repair-disk utility:

1. download boot-repair-disk .iso file from here
2. burn it on a DVD or USB stick
3. boot your PC from it
4. Select "Recommended repair" that solves the majority of bootsector/GRUB/MBR problems

more information on : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1831869

Comment: sourceforge is temporarily off line....

Comment: Hi luca, yes you are right sourceforge had trouble but it looks like the sourceforge.net website is back online, if you want to try, you can access it [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)

Comment: Thank you again, i will download   the boot-repair-disk utility.  
Right now i am writing from my pc. The system came up when I choose the second option in Ubuntu--> advanced option  in  GRUB